# Why is my Jquery function not changing the height of my textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here are the stylesheet excerpts for the panel class which I am using to edit the text area and "textarea".

```
.panel{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

textarea{
  resize: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-color: grey;
}
```

Below is the stylesheet excerpt for "topbar", the header above the text area.

```
#topbar{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Here is the div that contains my textarea (The bodyContainer id is not styled)

```
<div id="bodyContainer">
  <textarea id="TextPanel" class="panel">Hello World</textarea>
  <iframe id="outputPanel" class="panel"></iframe>
</div>
```

Below are the Jquery computations intended to edit the textarea's height.

```
$(".panel").height($(window).height() - $("#topbar").height() - 15);
$(".panel").width($(window).width()/2 -10;
```

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Missing one close `)` for the second line jquery ... chekc your console https://jsfiddle.net/j202cbf0/

Comment: is your javascript code bellow the document?, try to put your code inside this
$(document).ready(function(){  //put your code here   }); , and you know $(".panel") is changing the height of textarea and iframe too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the css incorrectly. And i would recommend you also use variables

like

```
var h= $(window).height() - $("#topbar").height() - 15;
var w = $(window).width()/2 -10 ;

$(".panel").css( "height", h );
$(".panel").css( "width", w );
```

Give that a whirl

Comment: but you can't set a height that isn't in your css already. add a default height or auto

Comment: You can set also the dimensions with jquery `height()` and `width`. So there is no *incorrectly* way

Comment: Also redundant to make 2 dom searches for 2 css() calls when object can be used for one